# How to send a curl in Docker Remote API?

Tags: docker, certificate, ssl-certificate, docker-compose

I am using [docker remote api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/) in a docker machine and I want to get the images I tried to follow the specifications to connect to a docker machine but I got errors, I also tried for example

```
 curl --cacert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/ca.pem https://10.0.1.17:2376/images/json
```

but I got `Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to ...`

Does anyone know how to solve this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving this error because the server is not authenticating the client, you should pass your key also

1st generate a .p12 using

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -certfile ca.pem
```

you will be asked for a password that you will use it later, I will assume that the password you entered is mypass

Now you can use

`curl https://10.0.1.17:2376/images/json --cert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/certificate.p12 --pass mypass --key $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/key.pem --cacert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/ca.pem`